# to keep the script running even after internet connection goes off

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, putty

I had putty on one server and run a python script available on that server. That script keep on throwing output on terminal. Later on, my internet connection went off but even then i was expecting my script to complete it job as script is on running on that server. But when internet connection resumed, I found that script has not done its job.
So is this expected ? If yes, then what to do to make sure that script runs on server even though internet connection goes off in-between?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [screen](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/) which will let you "detach" your process from the actual terminal you're in.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, you can install `tmux` or screen. These programs run the program in the background and enable you to open a 'window', If I use tmux:

**Open tmux:** `tmux`

**Detach (run in background):** press Ctrl-b d

**reattach (open a 'window'):** `tmux attach`